# Javascript in html - Using single quote inside another single quote

Tags: javascript, quotes

```
document.getElementById("img").innerHTML="< img src='/sitepath/"+imgg+".jpg' width='72' height='44' onclick='alert('hello');' />";
```

The above code is my javascript. Problem is printing hello or any other string. If I just type 123 in place of hello, it does give alert. But am not able to use a string like hello there. Normally a string in an alert function is kept inside quotes ' ' but the entire content is inside double quotes and I have already used single quote at the beginning of onclick function. I tried using Escape character ("\") but it didnt help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you pick a correct answer here?

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = '<img src="/sitepath/' + imgg + '.jpg" width="72" height="44" onclick="alert(\'hello\');" />';
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use apostrophes as delimiter for the HTML attributes, you have to HTML encode the apostrophes that you put inside the attribute:

```
document.getElementById("img").innerHTML="< img src='/sitepath/"+imgg+".jpg' width='72' height='44' onclick='alert(&#39;hello&#39;);' />";
```

I prefer using apostrophes as string delimited in Javascript and quotation marks as delimiters for HTML attributes. Then you just escape the apostrophes that you have inside the Javascript string:

```
document.getElementById("img").innerHTML='< img src="/sitepath/'+imgg+'.jpg" width="72" height="44" onclick="alert(\'hello\');" />';
```

To put any string inside a Javascript, inside an HTML attribute, inside a string in Javascript, you do:

- escape any string delimiters in the string
- HTML encode the Javascript code
- escape any string delimiters in the HTML string

Comment: They aren't apostrophes: they're single quotes. Apostrophes are the same character, but serve quite a different grammatical function.

Comment: @TRiG: Yes, they are apostrophes. To be specific, it's a "typewriter apostrophe". A quote is not a character at all, it's the text that you put between quotation marks, so to be correct you should call it "single quotation mark" which is a bit cumbersome, and still not really correct as that is a different character. The real quotation marks (single, double and all the others) are typographic characters, and not what's used in Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You have JavaScript inside HTML inside JavaScript. That's naturally confusing. Better to avoid the string-slinging problems of quoting and escaping (which, got wrong, can easily lead to security holes when user-submitted data is used), and do it the DOM way:

```
var img= new Image();
img.src= '/sitepath/'+imgg+'.jpg';
img.width= 72;
img.height= 44;
img.onclick= function() {
    alert('hello');
};
document.getElementById('img').appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using Escape character ("\") but it didnt help

Javascript is different from C#, you just use it twice at a time, example: `alert('We are\\'t going to go')`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the double quotes and escape it in the onclick attribute

```
document.getElementById("img").innerHTML="&lt;img src='/sitepath/"+imgg+".jpg' width='72' height='44' onclick=\"alert('hello');\" /&gt;";
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if your outer quotes are single or double.  You can escape a character within an outer string with a backslash...  \'  becomes ' within the string itself.  Either Darin's or Masood's example will work.  But Masood is ignorant in reference to a need to use double-quotes as the outside enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

what if someone needs to send a variable instead of a string "hello"? Something like this:

```
function showContent(toPopulate) { 
      document.getElementById(toPopulate).innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:showOtherContent(*toPopulate*);'>show</a>"
}

function showOtherContent(toPopulate) {...}
```

so how to send toPopulate as a variable to showOtherContent()?

The above is solved like this:

```
document.getElementById(toPopulate).innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:showOtherContent(\"" + toPopulate + "\");'>show</a>"
```